# less . convert percents to pixels

Tags: css, less

I'm looking for the way to convert percents to pixels without js and use only less/css code. 
What I mean:

```
 @val: convertToPx(100%); // here I expect to get 100% converted  to px e.g. 350px

&-blocks {
   width: calc(@val / 5);
}
```

you are welcome to introduce different approaches how to solve this with less/css! Thanks!

Comment: You can't determine this through LESS/any CSS preprocessor, unless you have beforehand a static pixel value that the percentage is of. If it's a percentage of something that can be dynamically resized by the client, you'll have to use JS to calculate this dynamically. On a related note, why not just use the percentage directly? `calc()` can handle that.

Comment: I think you are confusing compile-time and run-time. LESS cannot do *anything* for you on run-time.

Comment: Looking at your first comment on MrSp33dy123's answer, seems like you could just do `width: calc(100%/5)` or, if you need the calculation to be visible in the css, `width: calc(~'100%/5')`

Comment: Calc(100%/5) returns percentage value

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be a little confused. To 'convert' a percentage to a value, you need to have an original value to multiply the percentage by. "convertToPx(100%)" isn't something that you can do, but, for example, "convertToPx(200px,50%)" is something that could be done. The question is, you want to find 100% of *what?*

LESS has operators, so you could do something like `@val = (@percentage / 100) * @baseval`.

Comment: answering your question. Parent element has width 100% and has 5 child element so i want to set fixed width to all child elements depending on parent element width. Their width were calculated like so : 100%(of parent) / 5(child elements) = e.g. 120px(width of child elements)

Comment: @Palatnyi Less is compiled before the generated CSS is tied to any HTML so it simply can't have any idea of any "parent element" (neither its width, nor its children count, nor if anything of this exists at all). So as suggested in previous comments use `calc` instead.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks!  This is the answer I was looking for. Less doesn't know anything about any parent or child blocks.